# convert flask application into aws lambda using Zappa

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I have a `flask_application` which will do some simple task.

**My Requirement:** I want to deploy this `flask_application` as a aws lambda_function with the help of `zappa`

To run my flask_application as a lambda function, i am performing

1. zappa init
2. zappa package

and then i am uploading that zipped file into lambda and running my lambda function.

**My Issue:**
when ever i run `zappa init` command, it is creating a `zappa_setting.json` file with some info like below

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "flask.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "profile_name": "dev",
        "project_name": "flask",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-p5m0kuurp"
    }
}
```

I have 3 aws environments and seperate buckets for each environment like

```
test  ==> zappa_test_bucket
stage ==> zappa_stage_bucket
prod  ==> zappa_prod_bucket
```

I want to deploy my flask application in all 3 aws environments by providing custom `zappa_settings.json`.

**Question:**
Is there a way to provide `zappa_settings.json` as a file and then whenever i run `zappa init`, zappa will take this file as a input and set these environmental varible according to environment.

```
zappa_settings.json

{
    "test": {
        "app_function": "flask.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "profile_name": "dev",
        "project_name": "flask",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa_test_bucket"
    },
        "stage": {
        "app_function": "flask.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "profile_name": "dev",
        "project_name": "flask",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa_stage_bucket"
    },

    "prod": {
        "app_function": "flask.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "profile_name": "dev",
        "project_name": "flask",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa_prod_bucket"
    }


}
```

**if anyone have an idea, please let me know**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that you use zappa init each time you deploy the code. After that you `upload your code to lambda` manually.

You must rather use the functionalities of zappa to the fullest:

- Use `zappa init` just once.
- Update your `zappa_settings.json` file just once.
- From now own, do your deployments with `zappa deploy dev/stage/prod`

See this minimal [flask zappa tutorial](https://github.com/ProfessorKazarinoff/flask-zappa-tutorial) to know more.

If there's something I'm missing and you really have to pass `zappa_settings.json` file, you can't pass it, but you can keep a backup in your repository as `zappa_settings.json.backup` and right after `zappa init` you can call `cp zappa_settings.json.backup zappa_settings.json`. This will save you from creating that file from scratch again and again.

Comment: got it @amsh, I have one more small question, when i run `zappa package test -o mypackage.zip` i am seeing 2 different zip files like `mypackage.zip` and `<PROJECT_NAME>-dev-1602262819.tar.gz `. which one is correct?

Comment: mypackage.zip should be the right one. This claim is backed by the documentation: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#package

Comment: @siva, if the answer was helpful, it's requested to accept and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: i will do that, at present to run lambda i am uploading these compressed files to s3 and my CI/CD setup will fatch these compressed files into lambda. finally my lambda will process the code.

Comment: do i need to upload both `mypackage.zip` and `<PROJECT_NAME>-dev-1602262819.tar.gz ` to s3?

Comment: Nope, only mypackage.zip is enough.

If you are using CI/CD, you should have environment name available for a specific pipeline run as well, right? Why should you upload it manually? You can simply run `zappa deploy <env>`. Please let me know if I'm missing something.